# Find features of a non Microsoft program

Tags: powershell-2.0

I'm not sure how to even ask this question, but let's say I have a program such as Google Chrome.  How would I find out the "features" of it so I can use PowerShell to modify it.

For example, how would I have Chrome open a web page and click a button.

I know for IE, you can use **$ie.document.getElementById("loginform").submit()** to click a button.

Thank you,

Tony

Comment: start-Process "chrome.exe" url

Comment: Thank you,I know you can path to the .exe to start a program, but how would I click a button for example in Google Chrome?  Without using sendkeys to press tabs and '~' for enter?

Comment: I guess my question is, how would I find out the settings for any program?  Would I look at the INI ? DLL?  Once I look at the "settings" in INI / DLL file, how would I modify it using PowerShell?

Answer (score 0):

You can't ever really get the same amount of control over non-Windows programs using Powershell.

In terms of Chrome, you could simply open the browser and go to a webpage with:

`$Start-Process "chrome.exe" "www.google.com"`

There is generally not that much more for further functionality, but with Chrome you may be able to do things like change settings and configuration. Check out the (large) JSON file `Preferences` and other config files, which you can find in Chrome's local appdata folder (Win+R, `%localappdata%`, Google/Chrome/User Data/Default). I'm not too sure but it may also be a bad idea to mess around with these files.

I also did a Google search and found this third party powershell tool for browsers, called [Selenium](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/). Here's the [list of extensions.](http://sepsx.codeplex.com/)